# Flutter - I'm having trouble passing arguments with Get.to

Tags: flutter

I wrote a code like this:

```
Get.to(const UnderRublePeopleDetailPage(), arguments: data[index]);
```

I am sending the details to the detail page with this code. However, when I exit the page and enter the detail page of another record, the data is not updated. Why could this be? When I print the data I sent in the above code to the console, the details of the record I clicked go correctly. However, this does not change on the detail page.

Detail Page:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:safearea/Model/DebrisPeople.dart';

final DebrisPeopleModel data = Get.arguments;

class UnderRublePeopleDetailPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const UnderRublePeopleDetailPage({super.key});
  @override
  State<UnderRublePeopleDetailPage> createState() =>
      _UnderRublePeopleDetailPageState();
}

class _UnderRublePeopleDetailPageState
    extends State<UnderRublePeopleDetailPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print(data.nameSurname);
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("Depremzede Bilgisi"),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 12, right: 12),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            const Center(
              child: Icon(
                Icons.person,
                size: 150,
                color: Color(0xFFCB3126),
              ),
            ),
            Row(
              children: [
                FieldText("Ad-Soyad:"),
                InformationTextField(
                  context,
                  data.nameSurname.toString(),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 10),
            Row(
              children: [
                FieldText("Telefon Numarası:"),
                InformationTextField(
                  context,
                  data.phone.toString(),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 10),
            Row(
              children: [
                FieldText("İl / İlçe / Mahalle:"),
                InformationTextField(
                  context,
                  "${data.city} / ${data.district} / ${data.neighbourhood}",
                ),
              ],
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 10),
            Row(
              children: [
                FieldText("Adres:"),
                InformationTextField(
                  context,
                  data.adress.toString(),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 10),
            Row(
              children: [FieldText("")],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget FieldText(String value) {
    return Expanded(
      flex: 2,
      child: Text(
        value,
        style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget InformationTextField(BuildContext context, String value) {
    return Expanded(
      flex: 6,
      child: SizedBox(
        child: TextFormField(
          enabled: false,
          initialValue: value,
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, fontFamily: "Roboto"),
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 0),
            fillColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 237, 237, 237),
            filled: true,
            border: OutlineInputBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
              borderSide: const BorderSide(
                color: Color(0xFFCB3126),
              ),
            ),
            disabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
              borderSide: const BorderSide(
                color: Color(0xFFCB3126),
                width: 1.5,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Values ​​in `TextFormField` do not change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can see, It looks like you're trying to get the data outside of your widget. But `GetX` router is sending the data to your widget.

So most probably this will fix the issue for you

```
 class _UnderRublePeopleDetailPageState extends State<UnderRublePeopleDetailPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  final DebrisPeopleModel data = Get.arguments as DebrisPeopleModel;
  print(data.nameSurname);
    return Scaffold(...
```

Basically you can get the arguments inside your `build` method. And then, try to get the data like this

```
InformationTextField (
   context,
   "${data.city} / ${data.district} / ${data.neighbourhood}",
 ),
```

This works perfectly fine. If you're not sure that you're sending the `argument` every time on that page. You can add some `null` checks. Something like this

```
final DebrisPeopleModel data = Get.arguments as DebrisPeopleModel?;
```

Comment: However, I was able to return. It worked, thanks!